# Add several bibliographies

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I tried to add a second bibliography to my LaTeX document, but the second one isn't taken into account. The references that I mention within my text are replaced by a question mark. Can you tell me how to solve it ?

I added the second bibliography by using the following commands

```
\usepackage{natbib}

...

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{FirstBib, SecondBib}
```

**FirstBib** is linked with a Mendeley account but I can't add to it all the references, sometimes I need to write them myself on the **SecondBib** document.
If you wonder where I put both of the .bib files, they are integrated within the same project. The .tex file can find the first one but not the other one.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: In general Overleaf can deal with two different `.bib` files. Case in point: https://www.overleaf.com/read/dvnpshpmndqd. So there must be something else going on in your document. Please try to narrow down the issue and show us a fully compilable example document, an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). Since you are evidently not using `biblatex` I have retagged your question.

Comment: Remove the space after the comma.  It is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks @Johannes_B, the removal of the space after the comma solved the problem !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in comment